# Onboarding with custom animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

If I want to create **Onboarding Screen**  with custom page interactive transitions without any library. What should I do ?

Should I use `pageViewController` or `collectionViewController` ?

Comment: you can use `UICollectionView` with `horizontal` scrolling.

Comment: There is no definite answer to this. Some people like Apples over Oranges, this is just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `PageViewController` with custom transitions/animations.

Take a look at this post on how you might want to structure and build it.
Click [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/170144/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started).